# Visual Studio debugger does not exit after application was killed

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, keyevent

Whenever I run the code via *Visual Studio* after second run it does not exit, meaning it is still running but visually it is down, yet it is visible via *Taskmanager*. I believe it has to do with buffer being filled with keys and it cannot handle the flow (after running the code without the method showed below it works fine).

```
 _Controls _Movement; //Creates an object of the class

 public void MainWindow1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) //Eventhandler method, being called when key is pressed.
    {
       if (_Movement == null) 
          { //assign value to the object ONCE
          _Movement = new _Controls(CharacterBody, CharacterFeet); 
          }
     _Movement.Controlling(e); //calling method whether the key is pressed
    }
```

Above is the code where the method is being called when key is pressed it does call the method Controlling every time key press occurs.

```
class _Controls : MainWindow
{
    private RotateTransform rotateAll;
    private Image _CharacterBody, _CharacterFeet;

    public _Controls(Image _CharacterBody, Image _CharacterFeet)
    {
        this._CharacterBody = _CharacterBody;
        this._CharacterFeet = _CharacterFeet;
    }

    public void Controlling(KeyEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

After second run and spamming key or keys it does not exit. Yet it works well when I run it directly (.exe).

Here is the Output:

```
       'Shooter2D.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Shooter2D.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
       'Shooter2D.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Shooter2D.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
       'Shooter2D.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Shooter2D.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
       'Shooter2D.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Shooter2D.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
       'Shooter2D.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Shooter2D.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
       'Shooter2D.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Shooter2D.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
       'Shooter2D.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Shooter2D.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
       'Shooter2D.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Shooter2D.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Unranked\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Shooter2D\Shooter2D\bin\Release\Shooter2D.vshost.exe'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
       'Shooter2D.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Shooter2D.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
       'Shooter2D.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Shooter2D.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
       'Shooter2D.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Shooter2D.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
       'Shooter2D.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Shooter2D.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
       'Shooter2D.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Shooter2D.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
       'Shooter2D.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Shooter2D.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
       'Shooter2D.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Shooter2D.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xaml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
       'Shooter2D.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Shooter2D.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsBase\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WindowsBase.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
       'Shooter2D.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Shooter2D.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\PresentationCore\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationCore.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
       'Shooter2D.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Shooter2D.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
       The thread 0x1108 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
       The thread 0x1550 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
       The thread 0x1730 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
       'Shooter2D.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Shooter2D.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Unranked\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Shooter2D\Shooter2D\bin\Release\Shooter2D.exe'. Symbols loaded.
       Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'Shooter2D.App..ctor'
       'Shooter2D.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Shooter2D.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
       Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'Shooter2D.App.Main'
       Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'Shooter2D.App.InitializeComponent'
       'Shooter2D.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Shooter2D.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.Aero\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.Aero.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
       'Shooter2D.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Shooter2D.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemXmlLinq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemXmlLinq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
       'Shooter2D.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Shooter2D.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemXml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemXml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
       'Shooter2D.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Shooter2D.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationTypes\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\UIAutomationTypes.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
```

How would it be possible to make the software exit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try setting

```
App.Current.ShutdownMode = System.Windows.ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;
```

This will force the application to shut down as soon as the Main window
of your application has been closed.

> Side note: It looks like you're trying to build a game loop, WPF might
>   not be   the best solution for that. You may want to look into
>   MonoGame or Unity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does fix the not being able to run the application after several runs yet Shooter2D.vshot.exe*32 still is active after exit. Which is the part I want fix as well.
On Side note, thanks but I do have my own reasons for that :)

Comment: That is quite normal. *.vhost.exe is a process kept alive by Visual Studio. There is nothing that will change that. That said,  you're doing some very strange things there. Your KeyDown event is creating an instance of _Controls which is a subclass of MainWindow... (also don't use _ in class/variables names in c#)

Comment: Made an incorrect comment. I figured it was the debugger process. Yet after build the application is being ran normally second time it has some errors which it cannot bypass, it show orange line instead of blue meaning it is debugging which shouldn't happen if I make the application run not debug.

Comment: Are you running your comments through a translate engine? What's your native language, it might help me understand exactly what you mean.

Comment: I have figured I could have avoided this by changing few things. Thanks for the answer your insights made me realize them. Thanks and have a great day!

Comment: Ok, if not just give a shout :)

Comment: Well if you are willing I would like to know why it would not exit on its own after it was killed (pressed x)?

Comment: Hard to tell with the little code in your question, but most of the time this happens when you spawned another thread or another window hasn't been closed.. Since your _Control class inherits from MainWindow you created a new WPF Window, which you may or may not have shown on the screen. If not it wouldn't be visible to the user but it's still there. By default WPF only closes the app when ALL windows have been closed.

Comment: So whenever a class inherits  : Window the new window will be created? Well that explains why I had my problem. Thanks!
If you got some more time I got more questions if that would not be a problem :)

Comment: If you have more questions you'd better create some new questions here on SO. It's best not to have to much comments on a single question.